# How many different sequences in this event?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

There are $10$ students in the class. Four of these students will be selected randomly to participate in the math contest. Then, how many different sequences can four students be selected? 
I thought that I can use $^{10}P_4$, but it gave me the wrong answer.
Can someone guide me though this problem?
Thanks for answering!

Comment: Are you sure you mean sequences? It seems to me that 10P4 should work. If you meant combinations, then you should use 10C4. In terms of the logic of the question, why would the order of students picked for a competition matter?

Comment: Yes. I am sure it means sequences. It is not 10C4 either.

Comment: So what is the correct answer then?

Comment: I just checked that it is 4! It just doesn't make sense for me. Can you help me justify this 4! out of the question?

Comment: The only way that makes any sense to me is that the phrasing of the question is terrible. i.e. Suppose the teacher picked 4 students and NOW you want all of the sequences for those particular 4 students. Otherwise, I do not see a solution. Are you sure the answer key is not flawed in some way etc?